# What flower is this?

Tags: flowers

I saw this flower growing in my grandma's house when I was a kid.
I thought it could be some kind of lily, but after googling found that many so called lilies are not actual lilies.

[image: This is the flower]

Can anybody tell me what flower is this ?

Comment: An *Audrey II* clipping!!  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is commonly known as *Amaryllis*, however it is actually [*Hippeastrum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippeastrum). It is more related to daffodils, not so much to lilies.

These plants are often grown from bulbs, in the living room, and bloom around Christmas. You can keep the plant and bulb for next year, if treated properly it will bloom again (it needs a small cold period though).

Comment: Really, daffodils ? But they look so much different than daffodils. Anyway, didn't know all that. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: *Daffodils* and *Hipeastrum* are both members of the same subfamily called [*Amaryllidoideae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaryllidoideae). Lillies are not.

Comment: Liliaceae have superior ovary (you see the green "seed" inside the tepals), Amarylliaceae have inferior ovary (the seed growths below the tepals, in the "stem").

Comment: https://pets.thenest.com/amaryllis-toxic-cats-6041.html  Still considered a poisonous lily type plant to cats...!